# Get product on cart page using attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to display a specific product on cart page using attribute . on cart page phtml file i am implementing php code but its not been working . any help appreciated.

**based on comment**

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?> <?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProdu‌​ctId()) ?> 
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cartvalue')->getFron‌​tend()->getValue($_p‌​roduct); ?>
```

Comment: what code you have tried so far ??

Comment: <?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cartvalue')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

Comment: where cartvalue set to yes on cart.phtml, and this code just breaking cartfrontend

Comment: so if any product has display cart yes then need to display is this your requirement

Comment: yes , i want to display if cartvalue set to yes

Answer (score 1):

you can try  below code that will fetch all product where yourAttribute Value set to yes

```
<?php  
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('cartvalue',array('eq' => 1));
     foreach($collection as $product ){
         //your logic
      }



?>
```

Comment: what to write in your logic ??

Comment: @ManS. your fetching code what you want to fetch from product

Comment: its loading nothing

Comment: var_dump($product); returning nothing and cart page is also broken

Comment: @ManS. what error you get ??

Comment: no error , half of cart page been displayed where i put this bunch of code

Answer (score 0):

You can get value by this code:

```
 $item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('cartvalue')->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());
```

Or For better way use this code in your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <cartvalue/>                   
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

And get value by this code:

```
$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('cartvalue');
```

**[Edite]**

You can create a basic module:
First file we will create is Excellence_Test.xml file in location app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Test>  
            <active>true</active>  
            <codePool>local</codePool> 
        </Excellence_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next we create the configuration file of the module: config.xml inside folder Excellence/Test/etc. So etc/config.xml is created

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </Excellence_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <cartvalue/>                   
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: and where can i find config.xml ?

Comment: are you familiar with custom module app/code/local/Namespace/Mymodule/etc/config file. ? if you have custom module then add it here

Comment: i can go till app/code/local

Comment: Did you tried first method. ?

Comment: yes , that just broke the cart.phtml page

Comment: @ManS. I have updated the answer please check

Comment: where to create Excellence/Test/etc ?

Comment: under app/code/local/

Comment: again the page broken with this -- $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('cartvalue');

Comment: Please share errors

Comment: i am getting no error . just half page been loading rest broken

Comment: @Man I am using same code in my magento1.9x it's working fine. check your code there might be issue.